# Error when splitting dataframe with a function and calling the dataframe individually in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

I have created a function which takes dataframe and % split as input and creates two new dataframes based on inputs

```
def splitdf(df,split=0.5):

    a = df.iloc[:int(len(df)]*split)]
    b = df.iloc[int((1-split)*len(df)):]
```

Now, when I run this function and call "a"

```
splitdf(df)
display(a)
```

I get the error: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: what is return of splitdf???

Comment: It should not print anything but when called should give two dataframes a and b

Comment: in your function write return a,b  and when calling function a,b = splitdf(df)

Comment: Any way where inside this function only I can split the "a" and "b" df and can call it individually anywhere by just a and b?

Comment: If a and b are local to the function.,they cannot be accessed outside the function. They are basically no longer available after function's scope is exited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` are local to `splitdf`, so you have to return them.

```
def splitdf(df,split=0.5):
    a = df.iloc[:int(len(df)]*split)]
    b = df.iloc[int((1-split)*len(df)):]
    return a, b
```

Then when you call splitdf, assign the return values to some variable(s):

```
df_a, df_b = splitdf(df)
```

You are currently just defining `a` and `b` within `splitdf`, and then they stop existing when the function exits because they've gone out of scope.